# store/access activity metadata in datapackage created with brightway data

Tags: brightway

When I define a datapackage with with bw2data. How can I access metadata associated with the activities ? lets say I create a simple database :

```py
# biosphere
bio_db = bd.Database("mini_biosphere")
bio_db.register()

co2 = bio_db.new_activity(code = 'CO2',
                    name = 'carbon dioxide',
                    categories=('air',),
                    type='emission',
                    unit='kg')
co2.save()

ch4 = bio_db.new_activity(code = 'CH4',
                    name = 'methane',
                    categories=('air',),
                    type='emission',
                    unit='kg')
ch4.save()

# technosphere

a_key = ("testdb", "a")
b_key = ("testdb", "b")

act_a_def = {
    'name': 'a',
    'unit': 'kilogram',
    'comment':'just saying',
    'exchanges': [{"input": co2.key, "type": "biosphere", "amount": 10},
                  {"input": a_key, "output":a_key,'type':'production','amount':1},
                  {"input": b_key, "output":a_key,'type':'substitution','amount':1},
                 ],
    }

act_b_def = {
    'name': 'b',
    'unit': 'kilogram',
    'comment':'it depends',
    'exchanges': [
                  {"input": b_key, "output":a_key,'type':'production','amount':1},
                  {"input": ch4.key, "type": "biosphere", "amount": 1},
                 ],
    }
    
db = bd.Database("testdb")
db.write(
    {
    a_key : act_a_def,
    b_key : act_b_def
    }
    )
```

I can read the metadata of the associated datapackage with `db.datapackage().metadata` an even perform a calculation (as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230064/how-to-store-bwdata-databases-as-datapackages-to-reuse-elsewhere))... but data such as the name of the activities or the comments seems to be missing. Where is it stored or what needs to be done to store it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, datapackages don't have metadata of this nature - their whole point is to just have the numeric values for matrix creation. You would normally query the `Database` object to get such metadata.

However, you can ask for this metadata to be written as well. You will need to process the database again, with (in your example) `db.process(csv=True)`. In this case, you will get an additional resource, `<database name>_activity_metadata`, which is loaded as a Pandas DataFrame. In the example, this would be retrieved with `dp.get_resource('testdb_activity_metadata')[0]`.

Note that there was a bug, so this functionality requires `bw2data` version 4.0.dev16 or higher (released 2022-06-09).